# Should I move my question/answer?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question here a few months ago which didn't receive any responses. I was able to solve my problem using an alternative method and posted the solution I used.

After re-visiting this question though I'm wondering if it is actually more appropriate for ServerFault instead?

The Q&A I'm referring to is [Access Web UI running in docker container running on remote host](https://superuser.com/q/1201756/236843)

Should I request this get migrated to ServerFault or leave it as it stands?

Comment: Its too old to migrate, leave it where it is.